# show html text at the bottom of the JTextPane

Tags: html, jtextpane

I've been trying to show some text at the bottom of the JTextPane area using html. As it's not supporting styles, I used the following code:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0040)file:///C:/Users/tusim/Desktop/test.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
table { font-family:"tahoma"; font-size:11; width: 100%
}
td, th {
background-color: white}
.header {font-weight:bold;}
.record-first {font-weight:bold; min-width: 130px;}
</style>
</head>
<body><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" height="95%"><tbody><tr height="95%"><td width="32%" height="95%" valign="top"><div style="background-color: black; width: 100%;"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tbody><tr class="header"> <td align="center">Col 1</td> </tr><tr><td>Val 1</td></tr></tbody></table></div></td><td></td><td width="32%" valign="top"><div style="background-color: black; width: 100%;"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tbody><tr class="header"> <td align="center">Col 2</td> </tr><tr><td>Val 2</td></tr></tbody></table></div></td><td></td><td width="32%" valign="top"><div style="background-color: black; width: 100%;"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tbody><tr class="header"> <td align="center">Col 3</td> </tr><tr><td>Val 3</td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr><tr height="5%" valign="bottom"><td colspan="5" valign="bottom">some text</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

But although it's working on the browser, not in JTextPane. Can someone please help me out.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the JTextPane supports tables?

Instead of using the JTextPane, use the JEditorPane.
It can render HTML as well, although it has something called the
 `HTMLEditorKit`, which can parse HTML Documents.

Here's an example:

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit(); // Creates an instance
editorPane.setEditorKit(kit); // Sets the Editor Kit
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
But HTMLEditorKit seems not working either. Seems height parameter is not supporting.